# How can one drop/delete columns from a KDB table in place?

Tags: kdb

Following [the documentation](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/drop/#drop-columns-from-a-table), I tried to do the following:

```q
t:([]a:1 2 3;b:4 5 6;c:`d`e`f) // some input table
`a`b _ t                       // works: delete NOT in place
(enlist `a) _ t                // works: delete NOT in place
t _:`a`b                 // drop columns in place does not work; how to make it to work?
// 'type
//   [0]  t _:`a`b
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to use

```
delete a,b from `t
```

to delete in place (The backtick implies in place).

Alternatively, for more flexibility you could use the functional form;

```
![`t;();0b;`a`b]
```

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to achieve column deletion in place is using qSQL:

`` t:([]a:1 2 3;b:4 5 6;c:`d`e`f) ``

`` delete a,b from `t ``  -- here, the backtick before `t` makes the change in place.

```
q)t
c
-
d
e
f
```

Answer (score 0):

Michael & Kyle have covered the q-SQL options; for completeness, here are a couple of other options using `_`:

Using `_` as in your question, you can re-assign this back to t e.g.

```
t:`a`b _ t
```

You can also use `.` amend with an empty list of indexes i.e. "[amend entire](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/amend/#amend-entire)", which can be done in-place by passing  `` `t `` or not in-place by passing just `t` e.g.

```
q).[t;();`a`b _] / not in-place
c
-
d
e
f
q).[`t;();`a`b _] / in-place
`t
q)t
c
-
d
e
f
```